# Sorting an object array in VueJs is not reading the function

Tags: vue.js, hacker-news-api

I'm retrieving an object array from hackernews and trying to sort it by score here but nothing happens.

The console outputs the exact same array under unsorted and sorted.

What am I doing wrong here:

```js
created: function (){
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/beststories.json')
    .then((response) => {
      let results = response.data.slice(0,10);
      console.log("Unsorted: " + results);

      let sortedStories = results.sort(function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.score > b.score)
          return -1;
        if (a.score < b.score)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      });

      console.log("Sorted: " + sortedStories);
    })
});
```

Comment: This API returns `array of numbers` not an `array of objects`. Hence, there is no score property exist.

Comment: Hi @RohìtJíndal Im pretty sure its an object. And that function stored in ``sortedStories`` works if I call I put it under a computed hook. 
But here inline it does not do anything. Im thinking it might be a syntax error.
This is what the call returns: 
``{by: "marban", descendants: 3644, id: 31153277,…}
by: "marban"
descendants: 3644
id: 31153277
score: 2479
time: 1650887900
title: "Twitter set to accept Musk's $43B offer – sources"
type: "story"
url: "https://www.reuters.com/technology/exclusive-twitter-set-accept-musks-best-final-offer-sources-2022-04-25/"``

Answer (score 0):

The provided API url returns a list of sorted numbers. It's already sorted.